# Most efficient way to show $X^3-8X+16$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$.

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I want to show that $X^3-8X+16$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$. I'd like to know what the most efficient way to do this would be (i.e. shortest way to write something that works down in a way that is also clear).

Here's my method (with gory details removed): suppose $\alpha$ is a root. Then $|\alpha|^3 \leq 8|\alpha| + 16$. Suppose $|\alpha| \geq 1$, then $|\alpha|^3 \leq 24 | \alpha |$. So $|\alpha| < \sqrt{24} \approx 4.89$. Check all values in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ with modulus less than $\sqrt{24}$ and confirm they are not roots. Thus the polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Thus by Gauss' lemma, it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$.

Can someone do better? My proof takes a while since there's a lot of values in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ with modulus lower than $\sqrt{24}$ to check.

Comment: Well, it is a monic integer polynomial, and any root is an algebraic integer, which lets you show that if it has a root in $\mathbb Q(i):$ then the real root must be rational, and hence an integer.

Comment: Set $X = 2T$. The resulting polynomial should be easier to check for irreducibility.

Comment: Another approach is, if it has a root $a+bi\in\mathbb Z[i]$ then  $a+2b$ is a root in $\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z.$ You can easily check that it has no root.

Comment: We had some trick we learned that if there exist any rational roots they must be an integer root if it is monic and all coefficient integers. Then we can just check all the integers within reasonable distance to 0, out until the largest exponent term will dominate all the other terms of the polynomial.

Comment: There's a version of the rational root theorem that holds over any UFD. You can apply it to $\Bbb Z[i]$ here.

Comment: The polynomial has degree 3. If it was reducible, it would have a root in $\mathbb{Q}[i]$, Then Lukas Heger comment applies.